# the file route to linux kernel 4.7 task structure

Tags: linux, process, kernel, state

I am very new to linux and I want to figure out all the task's methods/states but I couldn't find find where it is located.

I am using this site to figure out the result: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/

Br,
new enthusiastic linux student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in sched.h file. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

> figure out all the task's methods/states

What do you mean by *task methods/states* ?

> I am using this site http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/

Linux Cross Reference by Free Electrons is a really good website that has the entire source code of every Linux Kernel from 2.0 to the latest 4.7. Go through the code to check how the kernel is being implemented.